# User Registration With Protected GraphQL Endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, graphql

I am creating an application using GraphQL and Node (express). Many of the tutorials I have viewed have suggested creating users using using a mutation:

```
mutation {
  createUser(username: "johndoe", password: "Tr0ub4dor&3")
}
```

Now I wish to protect my GraphQL endpoint `/graphql` with JSON Web Token authentication. Therefore, I expose an unprotected non-GraphQL endpoint `/token` which generates a token for a user already in the database. This token can then be used to access the `/graphql` endpoint.

However, a new user cannot obtain a JSON Web Token to access the `/graphql` endpoint since it is not already in the database. Therefore, it appears I cannot create new users using a mutation.

I did consider handling authentication purely within GraphQL using the `viewer` field and a `genToken` mutation of some sort; however, [this does not appear to be a good practice](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/571).

Therefore is my only option to expose a second unprotected non-GraphQL endpoint such as `/createuser` which handles user creation? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

What data do you want to protect from unregistered user?
Different with REST , Graphql only use same endpoint for everything.
Let say, example you have todo app, you have query to show todo that registered user already post.
You can protect the get todo query and add todo mutation with token.(please check out the context)
This context with jwt things are needed to be added for query or mutation that you want to protect.

You can check this post for further detail https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/authorization-in-graphql-452b1c402a9